# Getting Errors on the working code after adding appcompat_v7 library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, httprequest, importerror, android-appcompat

The code was working fine before adding action bar in project. The added library is `**appcompat_v7**`. After adding action bar the following problems occurred

Code:

> private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new
>   NetHttpTransport();

```
Error:
NetHttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type.
HttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type
```

Code:

```
@Key
public String id;
```

Error:
Key cannot be resolved to a type

I think the error happened because the **imports are not working**. The imports are

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

com.google.api.client.util.Key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding httpclient-4.0.2-sources.jar and jar for google places api can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-tools.** And upgarde to  **Android SDK Tools Rev. 22.3 and Android SDK Platform-tools to 19** if not available.

Comment: my Android SDK Tools is 22.6 and Android SDK Platform-tools is 19.0.1